# Will the joomla performance be affected if there is only one controller handling all the requests?

Tags: joomla, joomla2.5, joomla1.5

> The controller is responsible for responding to user actions. In the case of a web application, a user action is (generally) a page request. The controller will determine what request is being made by the user and respond appropriately by triggering the model to manipulate the data appropriately and passing the model into the view.

Source: [*Controller - J1.5:Developing a MVC Component/Introduction*](http://docs.joomla.org/J1.5%3aDeveloping_a_MVC_Component/Introduction)

So I was wondering, how many http requests simultaneously (json calls, xmls calls, http calls) can a single controller handle before it starts screwing the application? I could use multiple controllers, but honestly, how many requests can a single controller in joomla handle? or in other words Will the joomla performance be affected if there is one controller handling all the requests in contrast of breaking the logic into multiple controllers?

Comment: Shouldn't you be asking yourself "how much processing power do I have" and "how much bandwidth do I have" and "how will multiple controllers be balanced taking into considertion the available resources compared to one controller"?

Comment: Anywhere between 0 and Infinity requests. Closer to 0 if you're using joomla, though.

Comment: And what hangs behind your model, some database with its own limits?

Comment: Your question sounds a bit that you have absolutely no clue what you ask about. It's perhaps a good idea you add some more context because otherwise any kind of response might only create you even more question marks.

Comment: The only way to know for sure: **measure it.** Yourself.

Comment: +1 hakre is a superstar <3

Comment: @MattBall, I'm trying to use one of the [scripts](https://gist.github.com/mjball/802908/raw/c3e9421b468f1f51fdf12c53186cc1faa8a31a4d/stackExchangeUserProfileHacks.user.js) in your profile but it's being blocked by Chrome. How can I use this?

Comment: @naomik download the file, open chrome://extensions, and click-and-drag the file into the extensions page. Similar instructions @ https://agilebits.com/extensions/mac/chrome.html (though of course that's not my userscript!).

Comment: It's **not** the job of the controller to figure out which action has been specified. This is the job of the **router**. And instantly, joomla and it's documentation have no further credibility (not that it had any in the first place).

Comment: The questions is pretty clear. How much requests, which are web requests over http actually because we are speaking web. Probably thats the only puzzle that is missing in order to understand my question. How many http requests can a single controller handle simultaneously ?

Comment: one more key word "simultaneously"

Comment: @MattBall if I was to know how to measure this, I wouldn't have asked

Comment: @Gizmo how can I measure the ration between the http requests that are happening to the processing capacity of power that I have in order to do so? I don't know

Comment: @themis I think controllers support multiple threads so they will - no matter with how many - probably use all the available resources.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By thinking in terms of Joomla, you are just going to confuse the answer a lot, because you introduce a lot of extra factors. You could ask the same question about any PHP file, like so:

**Simpler question:**
I have a file called `script.php`, how many HTTP requests can call this file at the same time.

**The answer:** How ever many your server can support. Making two files (`script1.php` and `script2.php`) won't necessarily improve performance at all. It likely will have some improvement though, because ever php script that is called is loaded into memory and your server only has so much memory.

The second variable would likely be processing power. So the less that the controller has to process, the less load each call would place on the server. (So for example, if you were performing a calculation on a set of data but needed to display it in three different places on the page, only calculate it once and then save it in a variable that can be used for each display.)

In all of this, though, there is no magic number for the number of requests you could handle. Even if you ran tests and told us your controller could handle 72 simultaneous connections, that is a useless number.

**What you actually want to know:**

So, the test you actually should run on your server is the difference between one controller and multiple controllers. This comparison takes in to account your current hardware that you run the test on and helps you optimize the code.

And honestly on that note, I'm not sure that there will be enough of a difference to matter having worked with Joomla a lot. There are probably far worse bottlenecks in your code, and would do best to focus on standard optimization practices: [PHP code optimization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4176408/php-code-optimization)

As one final note, I do think it is valuable to have multiple controllers, but this is more so I can remember where the different functions are and what they do over an inherent speed issue.

Answer (score 1):

Generally, the controller is instantiated once for each single request, so each controller instance handles exactly one request. How many requests can be served simultaneously, depends on the resources available (and of course consumed per thread) and will vary from environment to environment.

Comment: So you are saying that since each request gets its own instance of a particular controller it doesn't really matter if there are n controllers or one controller responsible for the requests. What matters is the memory that could hold all those instances of that object that matters (Or now that I am thinking of, the number of commands that php has to execute on each request as well). So basically if you are right, could there be any benchmark for web applications.. I will google for that.

Comment: So the components are, The effort for the number of bytes that are sent + The number of server side commands + the number of instances that the cpu and memory can hold + the bandwidth of the line. I realize to many factors here

Answer (score 1):

it depends on the server you have. Read the article below

[HTTP Server Performance Tuning](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/httpserv/ihsdiag/ihs_performance.html)

http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec8.html